# How do I generate an ActiveRecord Relation and make sure to include specific objects within the collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to generate an ActiveRecord relation that looks like this:

```
@profiles = Profile.published.order("RANDOM()").limit(8) + Profile.where(demo_linked: true)
```

The issue with the above is that it returns an array, which is what I don't want.

I would like the above to be an ActiveRecord relation.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it with the following:

```
    @selected_profile = Profile.published.where(demo_linked: true)
    @random_profiles = Profile.published.order("RANDOM()").limit(8).where.not(id: @selected_profile.pluck(:id))
    @profiles = @random_profiles + @selected_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html):

```
random_published_profiles = Profile.published.order("RANDOM()").limit(8)
demo_linked_profiles = Profile.where(demo_linked: true)

all_profiles = random_published_profiles.merge(demo_linked_profiles)
```

Comment: I tried something similar....but what happens is that I just get the intersection of both queries...not the sum. Aka `[195] pry(main)> all_profiles.count
=> 1`, whereas the correct answer should be `9`.